# Discord.js V12 | How can i send a welcome message to users that has joined

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I want to send a message when people join my server by my bot in specific channel like this (JUST **specific server not others server that bot is joined on them**!):

```
Welcome {USERNAME_TAG}
Invited by: {THE USER WHO INVITE THE USER}
Member count: {CHANNEL MEMBERS}
```

I'm a new coder - sorry for noob question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event, which emits when a member joins a guild that your bot is in.

```js
// create the event
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
 // code..
});
```

---

The first and last requests are fairly simple. You can display the member's tag with [`member.user.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag), and you can get the amount of member's in the guild with [`member.guild.memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount).

However, your second request, while possible, will be a bit harder to execute. I recommend reading [this guide](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites.md) to learn more about invites and how to use them, but for now, I'll just use the code they show on their site.

```js
const invites = {};

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
 member.guild.fetchInvites().then(async (guildInvites) => {
  const ei = invites[member.guild.id];
  invites[member.guild.id] = guildInvites;
  const invite = guildInvites.find((i) => ei.get(i.code).uses < i.uses);
  const inviter = await client.users.fetch(invite.inviter.id);

  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID Here');
  channel.send(
   `Welcome ${member.user.tag}\nInvited by ${inviter.tag ||
    'Unknown#0000'}\nMember Count: ${member.guild.memberCount}`
  );
 });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but... @Lioness100
i need command that sey hello to pecific server not others server that bot is joined on them! h know how to say message in pecific  channel! i wanna but send message just when member join in my server not others server

Comment: Just add a `if (member.guild.id !== 'Guild ID')` line at the top. Please phrase your questions better in the future, it's very hard to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first and third things can be done. The middle thing, I do not believe can be done. Here is the code:

```
// Run dotenv
require('dotenv').config();

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get("channel id");
    channel.send("Welcome " + member.displayName + "\n Member Count: " + member.guild.memberCount);
})

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

There. We simply send that message with some data to a channel when someone joins.

Comment: is it just for my channel? bacause my bot is joined in 3 cahnnel

Comment: @Sarajohns you mean in 3 guilds? Then you use `channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'channel-name-here');`.

Comment: No bro,
I mean i need command that when user join just in my server send that message (not in others server) and mention persen who joined my server like welcome @GabRio Blu \n member count

Comment: @Sarajohns Just go to settings, Apperance, and go down and enable developer mode. Right click on ur channel of choice, and paste it into the string at `channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get("paste here");` If I understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh I think @Lioness100 answered better than me anyway :P

Comment: i'm sorry but no,
i need command that sey hello to pecific server not others server that bot is joined on them! h know how to say message in pecific  channel! i wanna but send message just when member join in my server not others server

Comment: @Sarajohns that's easy then. `msg.guild`. The server the message is in. I really hope I got that right.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use **guildMemberAdd**

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    client.channels.cache.get("YOUR CHANNEL ID").send(`Welcome ${member} To The Server!`);
});
```